# Popout message box in HTML (like gmail or okcupid)?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm not much of a client developer, so please excuse me if this would be a very easy thing to figure out with firebug. I'm curious as to how to implement something similar as the okcupid or gmail compose button. You click the button and the New Message box "pops out" on the same page you're viewing, allowing you to compose the message without taking you to a new page.

Any pointers on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: simply by using ajax, javascript, html and jquery

Comment: @leo just like building your own car is simply aluminium, steel, rubber and plastic, right?

Comment: @x0n yeah, that's right...and if you want to get into the engineering details, I would expect you already have a background in the subject, show that you have made an effort to actually do something and would ask a more specific question. Or shall we encourage everyone to post a tutorial here and vote for the best tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/popup/example.php

This will teach you how to create simple popup div's you can position and add content in.

Then use ajax to load your html page into the div.

This is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

The general concept you should learn about is Ajax requests. It's a technique that enables you to make requests from the browser to the server without having to refresh the original page. Ajax requests can be made using JQuery, and if you're using Asp.Net MVC or WEBAPI it is very easy to package content that can be requested using Ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **asp.net ajax control toolkit** .
You can install it to your project by

> Tools -> library package manager -> Manage NuGet Packages

ajax control toolkit  is a free framework for building a new generation of richer, more interactive, 
highly personalized cross-browser web applications.

[visit ajaxcontroltoolkit sample site](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx)